# Reactjs how to make the inputs in them work independently of each other, when you add a form button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I make the state in the added forms work independently of changes in other similar forms?
Forms are added through `locationAdd`

```
    const LocationBody = ({filteredServersData, locationAdd, 
       deleteLocationCell, handleChangeFilter, 
       filters, locationsData, envsData }) => {
       const classes = useStyles();
    
    const locationsSelect = locationsData.map((item) => {
       return <MenuItem key={item.locationID} value={item.locationID}>{item.name}</MenuItem>;
    })
    
    const envsSelect = envsData.map((item, index) => {
       return <MenuItem key={index} value={item.envID}>{item.name}</MenuItem>;
    })
    
    const serversSelect = filteredServersData.map(item => <Typography variant="h6" component="h1">
    {item.name}
    </Typography>)
    
       return (
          <div>
             {locationAdd.map(i => <Container className={classes.root} key={i.id}>
                <Grid container spacing={3} className="arr">
                   <Grid item xs={12}>
                      <Box display="flex" justifyContent="space-between">
                         <Typography variant="h5" component="h1">
                            Тестовая локация {i.id}
                         </Typography>
                         <IconButton
                            aria-label="delete" color="secondary"
                            className={classes.margin}
                            onClick={() => deleteLocationCell(i)}>
                            <DeleteIcon fontSize="medium" />
                         </IconButton>
                   

   </Box>
               </Grid>
               <Grid item xs={12} className={classes.filtersContainer}>
                  <Box display="flex" justifyContent="space-between">
                     <Box display="flex" className={classes.fieldsContainer}>
                        <Typography variant="h6" component="h1">
                           Локация
                  </Typography>
                        <FormControl variant="outlined">
                           <Select
                              value={filters.locationID}
                              onChange={handleChangeFilter}
                              label="LocationID"
                              labelId="locationID"
                              name="locationID"
                           >
                              {locationsSelect}
                           </Select>
                        </FormControl>
                        <FormControl variant="outlined">
                           <Select
                              value={filters.envID}
                              onChange={handleChangeFilter}
                              label="EnvID"
                              labelId="envID"
                              name="envID" >
                              {envsSelect}
                           </Select>
                        </FormControl>
                        {serversSelect}
                     </Box>
                  </Box>
               </Grid>
            </Grid>
         </Container>)}
      </div>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new component for `added forms` and each component will handle its own state only, without sharing it with other siblings.

Or, if you don't want to create a new component, and want to keep the current code as it is, you may differentiate each form's state by prefixing it with the form's unique ID.

Comment: Forms are created with a new unique id, please help me how to correctly assign a unique ID for these forms. Code for button: 

     `class idGenerator{
   static id=2;
   static next(){
     return ++this.id;
   }
 }

const ButtonLocation = ({addLocationCell}) => {
   const addhandler = () => {
      addLocationCell({id:idGenerator.next()});
   }

   return (
      <Button 
      variant="contained"
      onClick={addhandler}>
         Add location
         </Button>
         )
   }

export default ButtonLocation;`

Comment: Most of the changes have to be made inside a parent component of `LocationBody`. Basically, inside `LocationBody`, when you call an event listener passed from its parent component, you need to pass a unique ID of the form, e.g `handleChangeFilter(i.id)`. Then in an event handler of the parent component, process events and save results to `filters`, but with the unique ID. `filters` can take a form of `{id=>{/* form data*/}}`

Comment: This state `const [filters, setFilters] = useState(FilterDefaultValue)`  `const FilterDefaultValue = { locationID: "1", envID: "1",}`. I can`t add correctly `{id=>{}}` because an error appears